# XSLT1 how to reliably get data out of parent with variable amount of children

Tags: java, xslt-1.0

I have this really big XML file contains really old animal testing data, each row contains a set of fields, but each field is also again filled with multiple  fields. The file uses the sequence of the  children to determine the relationship between the actual data.

I need to extract these  fields in sequence of 'first all first data fields', then all the second ones, then thirds... ect. but the quantity of data fields is not set in stone for different rows, only in the same row it seems to be consistent.

Its hard to explain, but i added an example document, the first table is the source, the second one is where i want to get to.

I tried something like below to save the node relations but i couldnt get it to work. Id say im only barely past the beginner level of xslt, but due to the current infrastructure requirements i need to get this working in XSLT1;

```
<xsl:template match="ROW">
    <xsl:for-each select="./anamnese/DATA">
        <xsl:variable name="depth">
            <xsl:number/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select=".//anamnese/DATA[$depth]"/>
        <xsl:value-of select=".//diagnose/DATA[$depth]"/>
        <xsl:value-of select=".//fichenr./DATA[$depth]"/>
        <xsl:value-of select=".//vis/DATA[$depth]"/>
        <xsl:value-of select=".//dr._A/DATA[$depth]"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

An example of the starting table with bogus data. Note how the DATA fields are not reliable in the amount present.

```
<TABLE>
    <ROW MODID="4" RECORDID="1801">
        <anamnese>
            <DATA>Gevonden in lat decubitus. Dag van huis weggeweest. Vanmorgen nog goed gegeten.</DATA>
        </anamnese>
        <diagnose>
            <DATA/>
        </diagnose>
        <fichenr.>
            <DATA>3607</DATA>
        </fichenr.>
        <vis>
            <DATA>25/08/2017</DATA>
        </vis>
        <dr._A>
            <DATA>EL</DATA>
        </dr._A>
    </ROW>
    <ROW MODID="6" RECORDID="1802">
        <anamnese>
            <DATA>zeer agressief geworden op korte tijd</DATA>
            <DATA/>
            <DATA>detartratie nodig. Eerst cardiologisch onderzoek gehad bij Valerie Bavegems. Verslag volgt nog. Drinkt redelijk veel, 500 g afgevallen</DATA>
        </anamnese>
        <diagnose>
            <DATA> euthanasie</DATA>
            <DATA/>
            <DATA/>
        </diagnose>
        <fichenr.>
            <DATA>3989</DATA>
            <DATA>3688</DATA>
            <DATA>3608</DATA>
        </fichenr.>
        <vis>
            <DATA>2/11/2017</DATA>
            <DATA>6/09/2017</DATA>
            <DATA>26/08/2017</DATA>
        </vis>
        <dr._A>
            <DATA>EL</DATA>
            <DATA>EL</DATA>
            <DATA>MA</DATA>
        </dr._A>
    </ROW>
    <ROW MODID="4" RECORDID="1803">
        <anamnese/>
        <diagnose/>
        <fichenr./>
        <vis/>
        <dr._A/>
    </ROW>
</TABLE>
```

The desired end product;

```
<TABLE_B>
    <ROW>
        <recordId>1801</recordId>
        <anamnese>Gevonden in lat decubitus. Vanmorgen nog goed gegeten.</anamnese>
        <diagnose></diagnose>
        <fichenr.>3607</fichenr.>
        <vis>25/08/2017</vis>
        <dr._A>EL</dr._A>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <recordId>1802</recordId>
        <anamnese>zeer agressief geworden op korte tijd</anamnese>
        <diagnose> euthanasie</diagnose>
        <fichenr.>3989</fichenr.>
        <vis>2/11/2017</vis>
        <dr._A></dr._A>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <recordId>1802</recordId>
        <anamnese/>
        <diagnose></diagnose>
        <fichenr.>3688</fichenr.>
        <vis>6/09/2017</vis>
        <dr._A>EL</dr._A>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <recordId>1802</recordId>
        <anamnese>detartratie nodig. Eerst cardiologisch onderzoek gehad bij Valerie Bavegems. Verslag volgt nog. Drinkt redelijk veel, 500 g afgevallen</anamnese>
        <diagnose/>
        <fichenr.>3608</fichenr.>
        <vis>26/08/2017</vis>
        <dr._A>MA</dr._A>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <recordId>1803</recordId>
        <anamnese/>
        <diagnose/>
        <fichenr./>
        <vis/>
        <dr._A/>
    </ROW>
</TABLE_B>
```

How can i reliably extract all the DATA fields with the correct relation intact even if i cannot possibly predict the MAX amount of DATA fields possible in a row? (i've visually seen a row that had 266 :p)

Comment: You can use separate template for ROW structure creation, please see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have assumed that the node `anamnese` dictates the number of rows to be produced. If it has 3 children, it will produce 3 rows. If it is empty, then no information should follow. I just copied the nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="TABLE">
        <TABLE_B>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </TABLE_B>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ROW">
        <xsl:variable name="ID" select="@RECORDID"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <!-- Test for anamnese children.
                     If there is no child element,
                     copy the ROW child elements
                -->
                <xsl:when test="not(anamnese/*)">
                    <ROW>
                        <recordId>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$ID"/>
                        </recordId>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                    </ROW>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <!-- if there exists anamnese children,
                         loop through these.-->
                    <xsl:for-each select="anamnese/*">
                        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
                        <ROW>
                            <recordId>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$ID"/>
                            </recordId>
                            <anamnese>
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </anamnese>
                            <!-- loop through the following siblings of anamnese -->
                            <xsl:for-each select="../following-sibling::*">
                                <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
                                    <!-- select nodes with the same position -->
                                    <xsl:value-of select="*[position()=$pos]"/>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </ROW>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is the solution i went with because i completely understand how it works, i was able to iterate on it for my needs and it worked like a charm! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If `ROW` block structure is static, you can firstly define `ROW` block structure in separate template with parameters, and then pass its parameters in required loops, see below XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">       
    <!--prepare template for ROW block structure-->
    <xsl:template name="row">
        <!--pass recordId value-->
        <xsl:param name="rec.id"/>
        <!--pass ROW position number value-->
        <xsl:param name="row.id"/>
        <!--pass DATA position number value-->
        <xsl:param name="data.id"/>
        <!--creating ROW structure-->
        <ROW>
            <recordId>
                <xsl:value-of select="$rec.id"/>
            </recordId>
            <anamnese>
                <xsl:value-of select="//ROW[$row.id]/anamnese/DATA[$data.id]"/>
            </anamnese>
            <diagnose>
                <xsl:value-of select="//ROW[$row.id]/diagnose/DATA[$data.id]"/>
            </diagnose>
            <fichenr.>
                <xsl:value-of select="//ROW[$row.id]/fichenr./DATA[$data.id]"/>
            </fichenr.>
            <vis>
                <xsl:value-of select="//ROW[$row.id]/vis/DATA[$data.id]"/>
            </vis>
            <dr._A>
                <xsl:value-of select="//ROW[$row.id]/dr._A/DATA[$data.id]"/>
            </dr._A>            
        </ROW>      
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!--desired name of root node-->
        <TABLE_B>        
            <xsl:for-each select="//anamnese">
                <!--get recordId number-->                                
                <xsl:variable name="var.rec.id" select="../@RECORDID"/>
                <!--get row position number-->
                <xsl:variable name="var.row.id" select="position()"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <!--check if DATA block exists-->
                    <xsl:when test="DATA">
                        <xsl:for-each select="DATA">
                            <xsl:call-template name="row">
                                <xsl:with-param name="rec.id" select="$var.rec.id"/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="row.id" select="$var.row.id"/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="data.id" select="position()"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:for-each>                    
                    </xsl:when>
                    <!--proceed if DATA block does not exist-->
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:call-template name="row">
                            <xsl:with-param name="rec.id" select="$var.rec.id"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="row.id" select="$var.row.id"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </TABLE_B>       
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then try it with your input XML and result will be as desired:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TABLE_B>
    <ROW>
        <recordId>1801</recordId>
        <anamnese>Gevonden in lat decubitus. Dag van huis weggeweest. Vanmorgen nog goed gegeten.</anamnese>
        <diagnose/>
        <fichenr.>3607</fichenr.>
        <vis>25/08/2017</vis>
        <dr._A>EL</dr._A>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <recordId>1802</recordId>
        <anamnese>zeer agressief geworden op korte tijd</anamnese>
        <diagnose> euthanasie</diagnose>
        <fichenr.>3989</fichenr.>
        <vis>2/11/2017</vis>
        <dr._A>EL</dr._A>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <recordId>1802</recordId>
        <anamnese/>
        <diagnose/>
        <fichenr.>3688</fichenr.>
        <vis>6/09/2017</vis>
        <dr._A>EL</dr._A>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <recordId>1802</recordId>
        <anamnese>detartratie nodig. Eerst cardiologisch onderzoek gehad bij Valerie Bavegems. Verslag volgt nog. Drinkt redelijk veel, 500 g afgevallen</anamnese>
        <diagnose/>
        <fichenr.>3608</fichenr.>
        <vis>26/08/2017</vis>
        <dr._A>MA</dr._A>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <recordId>1803</recordId>
        <anamnese/>
        <diagnose/>
        <fichenr./>
        <vis/>
        <dr._A/>
    </ROW>
</TABLE_B>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
<xsl:template match="TABLE">
  <xsl:element name="TABLE_B">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ROW"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ROW">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="anamnese">
    <xsl:with-param name="RECORDID" select="@RECORDID"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="anamnese">
  <xsl:param name="RECORDID"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="DATA">
    <xsl:with-param name="RECORDID" select="$RECORDID"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>

  <xsl:if test="not(DATA)">
    <xsl:element name="ROW">
      <xsl:element name="recordId">
        <xsl:value-of select="$RECORDID"/>
      </xsl:element>

      <xsl:element name="anamnese">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      </xsl:element>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*"/>

    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DATA">
  <xsl:param name="RECORDID"/>
  <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>

  <xsl:element name="ROW">
    <xsl:element name="recordId">
      <xsl:value-of select="$RECORDID"/>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:element name="anamnese">
      <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:element name="diagnose">
      <xsl:value-of select="../../diagnose/DATA[$position]"/>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:element name="fichenr.">
      <xsl:value-of select="../../fichenr./DATA[$position]"/>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:element name="vis">
      <xsl:value-of select="../../vis/DATA[$position]"/>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:element name="dr._A">
      <xsl:value-of select="../../dr._A/DATA[$position]"/>
    </xsl:element>

  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```